# Add windows service in a Class Library(Output Type)

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have created a windows service and Installer in Windows application. It works well. 
For some reasons I need to create that service and Installer in another Class Library. But For this case after installing service the Service is not appearing in the 
Services list. Help on this!!

Comment: did you check in event viewer for the status of the installation

Comment: Better create Windows Service project from ground up [if not already done] and then copy Code in new project. And use Installer as in any basic tutorial. This usually fix all settings you might be missing and if not a big code will take 10-15 minutes of yours.

Comment: @saravanan Yes I have checked No error appears

Comment: You have to make sure that ServiceInstaller exists in the other class library among with the Service, namespaces must match. Also, if you are using vs install project, make sure you have set the correct install - uninstall custom action with the InstallerClass property set to True.

Comment: @user1612065: did you try to install using the procedure given here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192

Comment: @saravanan, that KB is not relevant.

Comment: @user1612065, is the project output of your class library added to the install project?

Comment: @mtsiakirs Yes I have added as dll file in detected dependencies and Project Output(another Windows application class)..

Comment: @mtsiakirs As you suggested I have added Project output of that class Library. Now Services gets in the SErvices List. But I cant start the Service.(The reason would be the path to execute shows as Class Library Path). I need another windows application path in it